# Export of BibDesk articles

Tags: bibtex

I am new to BibDesk and Latex. I was wondering if there is a faster way than exporting articles from BibDesk as a .bib file via the file -> export button to integrate those into latex? Isn't there any latex package which directly exports your articles form BibDesk?

So ideally I add a new reference to my BibDesk then copy the \cite tag and finally just rerun make (and other commands recompile latex and it is there.

Comment: I don't really understand your question (and I'm a long time BibDesk user). Do you know how `BibTeX` (not BibDesk) is supposed to work? You reference your .bib file in your LaTeX document. So there's nothing really to export here. You just tell LaTeX with the `\bibliography` directive which file contains your references and that's the one you edit with BibDesk. Or are you talking about a better integration between BibDesk and your LaTeX editor?

Comment: If you don't mind using `jabref`, there is one `push` option which puts the bibtex key in to the editor with a click.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, BibDesk saves data in a `.bib` file, so you *don't* need to export anything, so long as the database is in a place readable by the TeX programs.

If you save your huge `josh.bib` file created by BibDesk in the folder

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib
```

(create the structure if some of those folders don't exist, `~` represents your Home), then

```
\bibliography{josh}
```

in a LaTeX document will find all citations keys in that file.

Of course a `\nocite{*}` command would list in the bibliography everything you have in the big database and here's where the "export" function is needed: you can create a particular database from the main one for a specific document. But that's by no means necessary.

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks for that simple solution. I just changed the path of where BibDesk saves its .bib file to the one checked by latex and voila it works :) perfect thanks!

Comment: The other possibility would be to use the `BIBINPUTS` environment variable, which will tell BibTeX where to look for the .bib file: `BIBINPUTS=/path/to/foo.bib bibtex myfile` (this is a shell version -- there will be an analogous mechanism if you're calling BibTeX via a GUI)